# Using pre receive hook in git to identify the command run

Tags: git, githooks

Is there any way using a HOOK that I can find what was the command that was run from the client side. this should include all the command options that was sent from the client side.

for example I found out that there is a option with push called --mirror
(example git push --mirror) that will automatically delete all the branches that are not in the clients machine and will try to replicate the branches that are available in the clients machine.

If I could create a pre-receive hook where i can check what command options was sent with git push i could check if --mirror option was not used and that reject the command with out further processing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
thanks
Gopi

Comment: You can't do this, and even if you could, it wouldn't be useful. Someone could still come along and push deletions for all your branches manually - so that's what you should guard against. It'll take care of the `--mirror` case too. (And really, you could save yourself a lot of trouble by just using something like gitolite, where all the work's been done for you.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't see what command line options they used, but you can stop them deleting certain branches (by seeing what the command they ran actually does): See [Dissallow deletion of Master branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022438/dissallow-deletion-of-master-branch-in-git) for more detail.

Comment: I will not be able to do that because in our env we have teams that has tasks that multiple users are working on. Until the task is complete the users will not be pushing it to master. Users create a task based branch on the fly so that multiple users can share the code, complete the task and then push it to master and delete the task branch. Since the task branches are created(/deleted) by users We dont know what the name of the branch will be and no possible to  add branch names in the hooks. So if a user by accident runs push --mirror he will be deleting others branches.