# teamcity action on branch delete

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, branch, teamcity

I'm looking at maybe setting up a teamcity CI server for use with a git (github) repo.

I'd like to have teamcity build each branch that gets pushed to the main repo and it seems like TeamCity supports this now.

When a branch gets pushed I'd like to create a new IIS website/app pool etc for it all, and it seems like I can accomplish this with web deploy or something other similar.

The thing I'm wondering if its possible is that when a branch is deleted from the repo as its been merged into master/prod is there a way to get TeamCity to run a batch file/command in which I would remove all of the artifacts (website/app pool/db etc) from the server that deployed the site for that branch only.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if this is a GitHub or TeamCity thing, but it really should be added.

Comment: You can do this but it might require a separate app processing GitHub Webhooks. Steps 1) set up a GitHub Webhook on the repository for a [`delete event`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#deleteevent). 2) write some app/service that either triggers a TeamCity job or runs a script directly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you want, but why would you use TeamCity, if you could have done that using a simple pre-receive hook?

[See this for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022615/760757)